# Ordenar Columnas de Archivo Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Quisiera saber como puedo odenar las columnas de un Excel con VB.NET, por el momento abro el Excel con Interop , ahora quisiera ordenar las columnas ya que las tengo por el momento como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: Columnas Desordenada]

El resultado que quiero obtener es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Julio, el código que debes implementar es este.

```
    Sub ordenar()
For y = 1 To 9999 'establecemos un contador del 1 al 9999
    If Range("B" & y).Value <> "" Then 'si el valor de la celda B y (i)<---Contador
        For y2 = y To 9999 'Establecemos un segundo contador que inicie desde el contador anterior hasta 9999
            If Range("B" & y2).Value = "" Then 'este frena cuando encuentre vacio
                Range("B" & y & ":C" & y2).Select 'selecciona el rango
                Selection.Cut 'lo corta
                Range("A1").Select 'selecciona el rango A1
                ActiveSheet.Paste 'lo pega
                y2 = 9999 'pone los contadores en el final para que el loop termine
                y = 9999 'pone los contadores en el final para que el loop termine
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Lo que hace es recorrer la fila `B` hasta encontrar un celda que contenga algun valor, una vez lo encuentre hará un segundo recorrido para buscar el final de la tabla y asi saber desde donde hasta donde debe copiar para luego pegarlo en la celda  `A1`

Este código  esta echo para una tabla que no supere los 9991 registros y tampoco esta contemplado que tenga mas columnas hacia la derecha

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda el código, cualquier otra duda al respecto por favor hazla saber para que podamos ayudarte.